# How do the pins of this analogue switch correspond in this diagram?

Tags: integrated-circuit, datasheet, pins

Regarding an answer of my previous question, I want to use the following topology:

[image]

When the input is below the threshold, the comparator output is HIGH and the Analogue switch above outputs the set voltage. However if the input exceeds the threshold, the switch will output the input ect.

If I use [this](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/12b0/0900766b812b0f84.pdf) analog switch DG417(which I never tried before), does anybody know which pin corresponds what here?

[image]

Considering the above diagram for the switch, what does 0, 1 and X on the analog switch above correspond in the datasheet D, S1, IN, VL, S2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the DG419 SPDT switch. The DG417 is an SPST switch, which won't do for your application.

For the DG419, D (pin 1) would be your output. S1 (pin 2) is connected to D when IN (pin 6) is Low.  S2  (pin 8) is connected to D when IN is High.

Comment: Btw what is VL pin? Should it be grounded in my case? I will use single supply.

Comment: The "Electrical Characteristics" table in the datasheet shows VL connected to +5V. Under "Application Information", it says VL should be connected to +5V for the control input to be TTL-compatible, or to V+ for use with higher-voltage CMOS.  When in doubt, read the datasheet!  For single-supply operation, V+ must be 10 - 30 Volts.